# Make container fill only by content

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm facing a layout problem. I need to make a Window with a layout that works for these two situations:

[image]

I tried something with DockPanel, but this way the yellow container were stretching even with no content. I need to do something with the content (a UserControl) that makes it happen.

**EDIT:** "Image's "CONTENT FIXED WITH" = "CONTENT FIXED HEIGHT"

Comment: He may want the view to appear (but empty) for some reason we don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could use an `IValueConverter` for this...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <converters:NullableToVerticalAlignment FalseAlignment="Top" 
                                                TrueAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <custom:ContentWithFixedHeight />

    <custom:ContentWithVariableHeight Grid.Row="1"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{Binding Content,
                                                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self},
                                      Converter={StaticResource NullableToVerticalAlignmentConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

And the Converter itself:

```
public class BooleanToVerticalAlignment : IValueConverter
{
    public VerticalAlignment FalseAlignment { get; set; }

    public VerticalAlignment TrueAlignment { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? TrueAlignment : FalseAlignment;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom IValueConverter to switch the Height values on the rows based on whether the middle control has any content

Custom IValueConverter:

```
public class BoolToGridLengthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public GridLength TrueLength { get; set; }

    public GridLength FalseLength { get; set; } 

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? TrueLength : FalseLength;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <stackOverflow:BoolToGridLengthConverter x:Key="BoolToGridSizeConverter" TrueLength="1*" FalseLength="Auto"/>
    <stackOverflow:BoolToGridLengthConverter x:Key="BoolToGridSizeConverter2" TrueLength="0" FalseLength="1*"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=ChangingSizeControl, Path=HasContent, Converter={StaticResource BoolToGridSizeConverter}}"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=ChangingSizeControl, Path=HasContent, Converter={StaticResource BoolToGridSizeConverter2}}"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <UserControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="FixedSizeControl"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ChangingSizeControl"/>
    <UserControl Grid.Row="2" x:Name="MainContentControl"/>
</Grid>
```